# Looker Stopped Sending Scheduled Report Twice Now

Tags: looker

## Question

I have had Looker stop sending a scheduled report twice now. Once on October 31st 2022 and against on December 1st 2022. The schedules do not have an expiration date and still show up in the `Schedule` tab in Looker.

After the first incident we had an employee setup a second schedule for the Looker report. Their schedule has stopped working as well and we're trying to figure out what could cause this particular issue?

Answer (score 1):

## Root Cause

After looking at the datetimes for when these incidents occurred it looks very likely that schedules in Looker stop functioning when a user has their Google account deactivated. In this case we had both employee's who built the schedules leave in very close intervals and very soon after their exit date the reports stopped working.